# LEDs without resistors in parallel circuit

Tags: led, current-limiting

I have connected 75 WS2812B LEDs in parallel circuit as shown in manufacturer's datasheet:
[image: Source: https://www.tme.eu/Document/64e8d425b90f84990264129a9679149c/WS2812B-V5.pdf]
Source: https://www.tme.eu/Document/64e8d425b90f84990264129a9679149c/WS2812B-V5.pdf

Since all LEDs should emit the same color, it worries me that two of them are more bluish than they should be (see picture below). Is it possible that absence of current limiting resistors can cause such a problem? I connected LEDs to 5 V power supply, so I decided that there is no need to place additional resistor (since these LEDs can operate at 5V). Also, no resistors are seen in manufacturers circuit diagram.

[image]

Comment: These are not raw LEDs, but combo ICs and LED circuits which have built-in current limiting. You would never use current-limiting resistors with these.

Comment: It's far more likely that you haven't same the same instruction to each LED than for them to be so different by themselves.

Comment: Read the data sheet and look at the brightness table (min and max)?

Comment: Do they come from the same batch? What’s the guaranteed color accuracy from the datasheet?

Comment: @Tomass, it's been my experience working with LED manufacturers some years ago that their CIE hue varies enough to be easily noticed even when driven by precision current sources, and even amongst dice cut from the same wafer. Systems incorporating many in a display system where emitter-to-adjacent-emitter hue is important must be calibrated. I've written software that does exactly that using matrix methods on measurements made with a spectro-photometer. I'm not at all surprised by your results.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I guess there was just poor contact between LEDs and PCB. When I put pressure on them, the hue changes and matches with desired one.